# opencv attendance system mark student as present in csv problem

Tags: python, csv

i have an attendee system made with opencv, it works but my problem is with mark student in csv file, the goal is to mark student only once a day

/////////
after reading more about csv ive found that my logic was bad.

here is the latest code to solve my problem

```
def markAttendance(name):
today = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
if not path.exists('opencv/prezente/'+today+'.csv'):
    with open('opencv/prezente/'+today+'.csv', 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'{"nume"},{"timestamp"}')

    with open('opencv/prezente/'+today+'.csv', 'r+') as f:
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y,%H:%M")
        f.write(f'\n{name},{now}')
else:
    with open('opencv/prezente/'+today+'.csv', 'r+') as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()
        row_count = sum(1 for row in myDataList)
        exista = []
        for line in myDataList:
            if name not in line:
                exista.append(name)
        if row_count == len(exista):
            now = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y,%H:%M")
            f.write(f'\n{name},{now}')
```

so here is my markattendance function

```
def markAttendance(name):
  with open('opencv/attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:
    myDataList = f.readlines()
    for line in myDataList:
        entry = line.split(',')
        today = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
       
        if name in line and entry[1] == today:
            print(entry[1]+" ai mai fost azi " + entry[2])  
            
           
        else:
            now = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y,%H:%M")
            # f.write(f'\n{name},{now}')
            print("ciubaca")
```

i have comented the line f.write because there is my problem, from my logic that part should not execute if the condition is true but instead this is what i get in console

[image]

Comment: please remove the OpenCV tag. this question is not related to OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem you want to fix? My hunch is that you need an if elif statement instead of if else because right now the else statement could be triggering either if the name is not in the line or if entry[1] is not today:

```
def markAttendance(name):
    with open('opencv/attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            today = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
   
            if name in line and entry[1] == today:
                print(entry[1]+" ai mai fost azi " + entry[2])  
        
            elif name not in line and entry[1] == today:
                now = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y,%H:%M")
                # f.write(f'\n{name},{now}')
                print("ciubaca")
```

But I'd need more details on the problem to be sure.

Comment: the logic is this: if name is on the list and if entry[1] == today that means that the student was already marked for today, if the name is not in the list then i write it on the list, hope that makes sense, it is possible that my logic is bad ....